# ICS file is not adding event in IPhone. Any ideas to add event using ics in Iphone?

Tags: ios, node.js, iphone, angular, icalendar

`BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Welcome to our Wedding
LOCATION:91 Springboard
GEO:19.0759837;72.8776559
DESCRIPTION:Address More:b wing green view sosaity, Lower Parel, Friends Colony, Babhai Naka, Borivali West, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400070, India
DTSTART:20200425T090000
DTEND:20200426T050000
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR`

This is the ics file which is not adding event to the Iphone, However it easily opens. And It's working fine in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the colon and comma characters in the `DESCRIPTION` property with backslashes.

Also, try formatting the date values in UTC: `DTSTART:20200425T090000Z`

Comment: @Manjeet Yadav Did you try this solution?

Comment: Need to change like this ( DESCRIPTION \blah blah blah)